# Scale image by a factor, unless it hits container - with CSS only?

Tags: html, css

Suppose you have a container of `max-width` of 1000px, and an `img` that can be 1600px wide or 800px wide or anything in between. The goal is to, using HTML and CSS only, **always scale the image by a fixed factor**, say 2, and have it that width **until it hits the sides of the container**. So, in these examples these images would be 800px and 400px wide (and automatic height that preserves aspect ratio), and leave space at their sides until the container is resized past 800px or 400px, respectively. (Numbers are hypothetical and for ease of demonstration.) Extra markup within the `img` element itself is undesirable for legacy reasons.

Attempts so far:

- Work around `zoom` property. Downsides: still not supported by
  Firefox.
- The closest alternative, `transform: scale()`, behaves
  differently and keeps the original dimensions in document outline
  (thus, the height of the container will not be reduced).
- Hook up Javascript or PHP to check image dimensions and make the
  calculations. Downsides: extra markup or calculations where those
  might not be needed.
- It doesn't appear to be possible to get a hacky solution with
  `srcset` (also needs extra markup).
- Maybe this could be done with `object-fit` and combinations of
  containers?

Is such image scaling possible to achieve cross-browser as of now with just CSS, or JS/PHP processing is the only solution unless I completely change my approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution still requires pre-calculation of the maximum width (width * scale-factor) for the inner container, for example with a PHP script and `getimagesize()`, but it does avoid modifying the inner content of the inner container itself.

CSS:

```
#outer_container {max-width: 1000px;}
#inner_container {display: flex; margin: 0 auto;}
#inner_container > img {width: 100%;}
```

HTML in case 1:

```
<div id="outer_container">
    <div id="inner_container" style="max-width: 800px;">
        <img src="image_which_is_1600px_wide.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

HTML in case 2:

```
<div id="outer_container">
    <div id="inner_container" style="max-width: 400px;">
        <img src="image_which_is_800px_wide.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

One benefit of this approach is that it can be extended to flexibly host different inner content (not necessarily an `img`) without modifying it directly.

Answer (score 1):

CSS grid can approximate this in case you know the width. Resize the screen to test:

```css
.container {
  max-width:1000px;
  margin:20px auto;
  outline:2px solid;
  display:grid;
  justify-content: center;
  /* we set the step to be width/8
    for 1600px we get 200px
    our image will have a width equal to N*200px:
    [200px 400px 600px 800px 1000px]
  */
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit,calc(var(--w)/8))
}

.container img {
  grid-column:1/-1;
  max-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="--w:1600px">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1014/1600/600">
</div>

<div class="container" style="--w:1200px"> 
   <!-- here will have a 150px step (150px 300px 450px 600px 750px 900px) -->
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/1200/600">
</div>
```

Comment: Downsizing in steps is an interesting trick that can have different uses, but it looks suboptimal for the specific task. It also still requires prior knowledge of the width (which I was aiming to not require, to auto-fit most content). But this reminded of a simpler content-fitting solution with flex, thank you. (I will post that one separately.)